# jQuery UI slider with custom handle not working with Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider, ipad-2, twitter-bootstrap-2

i have a custom handle for my jquery UI slider that worked fine on my laptop as well as on my iPad (using ui touch punch plugin) against jquery UI 1.9.2 + jquery 1.9.0 + twitter bootstrap 2.2.1.

however, ever since i upgraded twitter bootstrap to 2.3.0, the custom handle no longer responds to touch on my iPad. it still works on my laptop, so i suspect it's something with an incompatibility with the ui touch punch plugin + whatever is happening with Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.0.

any insight would be super helpful. thanks in advance!

carolyn

Comment: Maybe you accidentally changed the order of reference to external resources.